# Find the dimension and a basis

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

Find the dimension and a basis of
    $V$ - the set of all polynomials over $\mathbb{R}$ of degree at most $3$
that vanish at the point $x = 1$.

So, I know that the dimension would be $4$ since the dimension of a set of polynomials at degree most $k$ would be $k+1$.(?). But the vanishing on $1$ part confuses me. Like how am I supposed to act with this fact? Also how do I find the basis?

Comment: Hint: Start by considering the basis $(1, x - 1, (x - 1)^2, (x - 1)^3)$ for $P_3(\Bbb{R})$.

Comment: I intuitively don't understand why there are these polynomials  for a basis. I know the definition of basis and i'm fluent in using them in vector exercises but cannot grasp why this would be the basis. Could you explain?

Comment: Could you please confirm whether you're happy with $(1, x, x^2, x^3)$ being a basis for $P_3(\Bbb{R})$? I also notice you've accepted Julian's answer; do you want me to write an answer too?

Comment: I can't confirm since I do not  intuitively understand why would it be a basis. And yes if you could explain it through an answer, would be cool.

Comment: I might argue that you’re not “fluent in using them in vector exercises,” as this _is_ a vector exercise: many objects besides ordered tuples of numbers are vectors. Intuition is something that must be developed: go back to the definition of a basis and try to understand how it applies to that set of polynomials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $W = P_3(\Bbb{R})$ be the vector space of real-valued polynomials. We consider this a subspace of the polynomials as a subspace of the vector space of all functions $\Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$, which is to say, we equip $W$ with the operations:
\begin{align*}
(p \color{red}+ q)(x) &:= p(x) + q(x) \\
(\lambda \color{red}\cdot p)(x) &:= \lambda \cdot p(x),
\end{align*}
where $p, q \in W$, $\lambda \in \Bbb{R}$, and $x$ is a dummy variable ranging over all $\Bbb{R}$. The two operations highlighted in red are the operations being defined here. The red $\color{red}+$ is a sum of two functions, where as the black $+$ is the sum of two numbers in $\Bbb{R}$. Similarly, the red $\color{red}\cdot$ is scalar multiplication of a real number (a scalar) and a function (a vector), whereas the black $\cdot$ is the standard multiplication on $\Bbb{R}$.

Recall the definition of a polynomial and its degree. Essentially, to say that $p$ is a polynomial of degree $3$ or less is to say that there exist some scalars $a_0, a_1, a_2, a_3 \in \Bbb{R}$ such that
$$p(x) = a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2 + a_3 x^3.$$
That is, $B = (1, x, x^2, x^3)$ spans $W$, basically by definition of $W$. If we can show that these functions are linearly independent, then they are a basis for $W$, and $W$ has dimension $4$.

There are a few ways to do this, most of which begin with assuming you have $a_0, a_1, a_2, a_3 \in \Bbb{R}$ such that
$$a_0 \cdot 1 + a_1 \cdot x + a_2 \cdot x^2 + a_3 \cdot x^3 \equiv 0, \tag{1}$$
by which I mean the two expressions are equal for all $x$. Naively, we can simply substitute in some specific values for $x$ into $(1)$, say $x = -1, 0, 1, 2$, to obtain a system of linear equations
\begin{align*}
a_0 - a_1 + a_2 - a_3 &= 0 \\
a_0 &= 0 \\
a_0 + a_1 + a_2 + a_3 &= 0 \\
a_0 + 2a_1 + 4a_2 + 8a_3 &= 0.
\end{align*}
Solving these four linear equations yields a unique solution of $a_0 = a_1 = a_2 = a_3 = 0$, proving $B$ is linearly independent.

There is a more elegant way too. Since $(1)$ is an equality of (infinitely differentiable) functions, we can differentiate both sides. In fact, differentiating both sides $3$ times yields
$$6a_3 = 0 \implies a_3 = 0.$$
Differentiating $(1)$ twice then yields
$$6a_3 x + 2a_2 = 0 \implies a_2 = 0.$$
Differentiating $(1)$ once implies
$$3a_3x^2 + 2a_2 x + a_1 = 0 \implies a_1  = 0,$$
and finally, $(1)$ itself now implies $a_0 = 0$. The beauty of this method is that it extends to arbitrary polynomials, not just ones of degree $3$ or less. Either which way, $B$ is a basis for $W$.

(Some people will prove the linear independence of $B$ by equating coefficients, but I consider this a circular proof. Equating coefficients is another way of saying the linear combinations of $B$ are unique, a property equivalent to the linear independence of $B$. In order to show that equating coefficients is valid, you need a technique like the above.)

---

Now, on to my hint. I suggested looking at the basis $C = (1, x - 1, (x - 1)^2, (x - 1)^3)$. There are a number of ways to show that $C$ is a basis for $W$, but I'm going to do it the naive way.

Consider an arbitrary polynomial $p(x) = a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2 + a_3 x^3$ in $W$. Let $u = x - 1$. Then $x = u + 1$, and
\begin{align*}
p(x) &= p(u + 1) \\
&= a_0 + a_1 (u + 1) + a_2 (u + 1)^2 + a_3 (u + 1)^3 \\
&= (a_0 + a_1 + a_2 + a_3) + (a_1 + 2a_2 + 3a_3)u + (a_2 + 3a_3)u^2 + u^3 \\
&= (a_0 + a_1 + a_2 + a_3) + (a_1 + 2a_2 + 3a_3)(x - 1) + (a_2 + 3a_3)(x - 1)^2 + (x - 1)^3.
\end{align*}
Hence, $p \in \operatorname{span}(C)$, so $C$ spans $W$.

On the other hand, suppose
$$a_0 \cdot 1 + a_1 \cdot (x - 1) + a_2 \cdot (x - 1)^2 + a_3 \cdot (x - 1)^3 \equiv 0.$$
Then, expanding
$$(a_0 - a_1 + a_2 - a_3) \cdot 1 + (a_1 - 2a_2 + 3a_3) \cdot x + (a_2 - 3a_3) \cdot x^2 + a_3 \cdot x^3 \equiv 0.$$
By the linear independence of $B$, we get
\begin{align*}
a_0 - a_1 + a_2 - a_3 &= 0\\
a_1 - 2a_2 + 3a_3 &= 0 \\ 
a_2 - 3a_3 &= 0 \\
a_3 &= 0,
\end{align*}
which clearly implies $a_0 = a_1 = a_2 = a_3 = 0$, i.e. $C$ is linearly independent. Hence, $C$ is also a basis for $W$.

(Note that we could have taken a shortcut. Since $B$ is a basis and has $4$ vectors, $W$ is $4$-dimensional, so we could have showed either $C$ is linearly independent or $C$ is spanning, and obtained the other for free!)

---

Finally, we can use this basis $C$ to find a basis for $V$. Note that each vector in $C$ belongs to $W$, except $1$ (since $1$ is a function that constantly takes the value $1$, hence it doesn't vanish at $x = 1$, or indeed any other point). If we remove $1$, we get a (necessarily linearly independent) list of vectors
$$D = (x - 1, (x - 1)^2, (x - 1)^3).$$
All three vectors in $D$ belong to $V$, so $V$ has dimension at least $3$. It is a strict subspace of $W$ (e.g. the constant function $1$ is in $W$, but not $V$), so the dimension is strictly less than $4$. Thus,
$$\operatorname{dim} V = 3.$$
Hence, any linearly independent set of $3$ vectors from $V$ (e.g. $D$) will be a basis. Thus, $D$ is indeed a basis for $V$.

Comment: Okay! Thanks a lot! Really gave me the insight. I understand everything except how (from what exactly?) did you conclude that ''Hence, p∈span(C)'' after showing the p(x)=p(u+1) part?

Comment: @ThePoorJew The $u$ wasn't really important in the end. The important part of that equation is that the first expression $p(x)$ was equal to a (complicated) linear combination of $1, x - 1, (x - 1)^2, (x - 1)^3$, i.e. the vectors from $C$. The span of $C$ is the set of all linear combinations of these vectors, so by definition, $p(x) \in \operatorname{span} C$.

Answer (score 3):

If it vanishes at $x=1$, then your polynomial is actually of the form $(x-1)(ax^2+bx+c)$, with $a,b,c$ free. So the dimension will be $3$.

Comment: Could you explain about the basis part?

Comment: So, your space is $V=\{(x−1)(ax^2+bx+c)\}$. Think about $(x-1)x^2$, $(x-1)x$, $(x-1)$, this generates your space and they are linearly independent.

Answer (score 1):

If $a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3 \in V$ then $a_0+a_1+a_2+a_3=0$, so $a_0=-(a_1+a_2+a_3)$

Thus $a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3 =-a_1-a_2-a_3+ a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3$ which equals $a_1(x-1)+a_2(x^2-1)+a_3(x^3-1)$, so the basis is $$\{(x-1),(x^2-1),(x^3-1)\}$$